# Why does `Podfile.lock` change `SPEC CHECKSUMS` section on `pod install` when nothing has changed?

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods, podfile, podfile-lock

I don't check in my `Pods` dir into source control.

If I run `pod install`, touch nothing, and then run `pod install` a few minutes later the `SPEC CHECKSUMS` section of my `Podfile.lock` changes.

Why?

```
pod --version
1.9.3

"react-native": "0.63.2",
```

`Podfile`:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'

platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'Myapp' do
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
end
```